# iOS In app purchase: Auto-renewable subscriptions by own system user account

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

I am trying to implement IAP with Auto-renewable subscriptions in my app. My app has his own system of users and I want to implement this behaviour:

In the same device, if the user logged buy a subscription, then the user logout and other user login, I want to this user can buy is own subscription.

All the information about what user has buy the subscription, with all the info about the transaction can be save in a server side, but even I can handle that, for avoid restore when the user which is logged is not the user which bought the subscriptions, but still this user can not buy a subscription because it show a popup which said "You are currently subscribed".

There is a way to implement this behaviour? or for each Apple ID only can be one subscription active at the same time?
There is a way of with same Apple ID, to different users of my own system account of my app logged can buy two subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question...
An Apple ID can only have one active auto-renewable subscription to a product at the same time.
If multiple users share the same device : if a user buy a subscription, log-out, then another user log-in and buy a subscription it will work. The subscription is linked to the user's Apple ID.

Comment: But I said logout not from iTunes account, logout from the user account of my app. For example two different devices with the same Apple ID can not have a subscription each one? only one for both?

Comment: No, two different devices with the same Apple ID can only have one subscription, since it's limited to one per Apple ID, not one per device.